# ICSP - how to isolate a pin

Tags: pic, icsp

I have jerry rigged a PIC programmer but I need to use the PGC/PGD pins as part of the actual circuit. I'd like to be able to flash the PIC without physically swapping it between the circuit and the programmer. Will this do the job?

CTL_ON,CTL_OFF (from the programmer) will be either 0,1 or 1,0 (never 1,1). CTRL_ON,CTRL_OFF will only change when the PIC is powered down.
CTL_ON will only be 1 when RB4/PGM is high (i.e. PIC is being flashed). These rules will be handled in the programmer firmware.

Do I need resistors on the lines going into the T3 and T1 collectors? If so, can anyone explain why? I've spent a lot of time looking at web pages about this stuff, but can't quite seem to grasp the fundamentals. Pointers to any tutorials for beginners would be welcomed.

Note that this is not about isolating the power supply, that's already taken care of.

In this partial schematic, the RB7/PGD pin is just powering an LED for example, and can only be used as an output (when CTL_ON,CTL_OFF = 0,1), which is fine.

[image]
<sub>(source: [skilbeck.com](https://skilbeck.com/static/img/circuit.png))</sub>

--update--

OK, so I guess I need a kind of switch which can be controlled by a separate signal from the programming device, like in the drawing below. Can anyone tell me how to implement such a thing? It needs to allow flow in both directions... Kind of like a relay, but for logic signals.

[image]
<sub>(source: [skilbeck.com](https://skilbeck.com/static/img/IMG_0604.JPG))</sub>

I think a bilateral switch is what I need, like this one:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b.pdf

Right? Or is there a simpler way just using resistors, diodes and transistors?

Comment: Have you looked at tri-state buffers like 74126?

Comment: tri-state buffer looks like exactly what I want, but I only have transistors. Also, the PGD line is bi-directional when the PIC is being read/written, so I guess I'd need two, right? One for each direction?

Comment: The fact that your programmer happens to be a arduino appears to be irrelevant.  If so, you should edit out mention of arduino and replace with PIC programmer.  That would make your question clearer, not distract from the real issue by bringing up arduino, and of course make it look like less of a adruino question.  This is apparently not a adrweenie question after all, despite the initial impression from the first sentence.  I have designed several PIC programmers and have things to say here, but not when that gets drowned out by the ardweenieness.

Comment: Ah, good point, I'll edit, hang on

Comment: OK, removed all references to Arduino. I think a bilateral switch will work, but presumably this is a common problem which has a 'standard' solution - any pointers in that direction would be most welcome!

Comment: Also is it really LEDs you're controlling from PGC / PGD or is that just an example? If it's just LEDs you could switch them with a FET so the lines don't get loaded and you don't care if they flicker during programming.

Comment: Not normally LEDs, no - could be anything. I need the programmer to just get off the pin when it's not actively reading from/writing to the PIC so I can use it for whatever I need in the application.

Comment: Analogue switches will do what you have drawn- in effect they are just FET's

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: your transistors are not right, and you don't really need the Arduino.

Option #1:
The PGD pin will be tri-stated (made input) during programming. So the programmer will end up driving PGD as well as whatever is connected to it.
Your programmer just might have enough current capacity to drive the load (LED) at low speeds, so you can go with just direct connection.

[image: opt. 1]

Option #2:
Buffer the output from the PIC using a transistor so that the programmer sees a very light load. This has the side effect that the LED will flicker during programming, but I'd do it in the interest of simplicity.

[image]

P.S: In circuit editor was just way too slow so used pen and paper.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm not sure I understand some of the things you're saying. - "You don't need the Arduino" - eh? I need it to program the PIC.  I need the PGD pin to be an input or an output during programming - I can see now that my scheme completely fails in this respect. What is the capacitor connected via a dotted line (internally?) to PGD for?

Comment: PGD has data coming from the programmer when PGM is asserted. The total load seen by the programmer on the PGD line is the internal capacitance of the PGD pin, and whatever external circuit you connect to it.

Comment: But PGD might also have data coming from the PIC to the Arduino (when reading/verifying the PIC contents)

Comment: I added some questions to the question - thanks for your time!

Comment: Just to be clear, the Arduino is directly connected to the PIC, there is no other programmer involved...

Comment: Ok is the Arduino doing anything other than programming the PIC?

Comment: No, it's just for programming the PIC

Comment: In that case I've totally misundersood the problem. I'll delete this answer and add a fresh one.